# Contract owned by a wallet

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Can a wallet address own a contract? There's a difference between the two. Would it be perfectly fine to transfer ownership of a contract to a wallet?

Comment: Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract, so I find this code snippet confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

We should first be clear about what we mean by "owner". Once deployed, a contract *has no choice* but to execute the bytecode when someone sends a transaction. If one wants to stop a contract, this is only possible if the original contract has a stop switch. The contract doesn't need to treat everyone the same, and there are obvious advantages to reserving the privilege of, say, using the stop switch, for a certain user. This privileged user can be thought of as the "owner" of the contract.

Really simple example of both ideas in practice:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract SimpleOwned {

    address public owner;
    bool public isRunning;

    function SimpleOwned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        isRunning == true;
    }

    modifier onlyIfRunning {
        require(isRunning);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function changeOwner(address newOwner) public onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
        owner = newOwner;
        return true;
    }

    function stopContract() public onlyOwner onlyIfRunning returns(bool success) {
        isRunning = false;
        return true;
    }

    function doSomething() public onlyIfRunning returns(bool success) {
        // anyone is allowed to do stuff
        // halted if the contract was stopped by the owner
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.